# Can not upload files with MobileFoundation Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We create an Java Adapter that calls the API to upload files via MobileFoundation. However, when the application calls the Adapter, it will result in a server error and will not work.
In addition, I have created a JavaScript Adapter, but the same error occurred.
Please tell me how to resolve.

Adapter that was created is as follows.

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadimage")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@OAuthSecurity(enabled=false)
public void postFileUpload(@Context HttpServletResponse response,
        @FormParam("image_type") @DefaultValue("") String image_type,
        @Encoded @FormParam("file") File file
        )
        throws IOException, IllegalStateException, SAXException {
```

(Since it is an error before reaching the logic inside, method contents are omitted.)

The error is as follows.

```
[12/5/17 6:09:38:687 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid URL encoding: not a valid digit (radix 16): 14
[12/5/17 6:09:38:688 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.common.util.UrlUtils.digit16(UrlUtils.java:114)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:688 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.common.util.UrlUtils.urlDecode(UrlUtils.java:94)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:689 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.common.util.UrlUtils.urlDecode(UrlUtils.java:66)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:689 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.common.util.UrlUtils.urlDecode(UrlUtils.java:121)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:689 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.HttpUtils.urlDecode(HttpUtils.java:94)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:689 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.FormUtils.populateMapFromMultipart(FormUtils.java:223)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:689 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processFormParam(JAXRSUtils.java:956)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:691 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.createHttpParameterValue(JAXRSUtils.java:877)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:692 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:837)
[12/5/17 6:09:38:692 UTC] 0000af3f SystemErr R       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:787)
......
```

Dummy JavaScript Adapter that was created is as follows.

```
function postImage() {
var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : "test/"
    };

    return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);}
```

The request is as follows.

```
POST https://*****.mybluemix.net/mfp/api/adapters/JsAdapter/postImage

POST data:
--4ds9bnG-WijS3-W773egmV2-qxb8LBZeUfEr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="timestamp"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

2017-11-20 14:55:22.128000
--4ds9bnG-WijS3-W773egmV2-qxb8LBZeUfEr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="button_no.png"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


--4ds9bnG-WijS3-W773egmV2-qxb8LBZeUfEr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="thumbnail"; filename="button_yes.png"
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


--4ds9bnG-WijS3-W773egmV2-qxb8LBZeUfEr--


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: close
Content-Length: 107452
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=4ds9bnG-WijS3-W773egmV2-qxb8LBZeUfEr
Host: *****.mybluemix.net
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)
```

Comment: The JS adapter you created - was this to perform the same task? Or you created a dummy JS adapter and it did not work?

Comment: I created a dummy JS adapter.
It also did not work like Java adapter.

Comment: Can you provide the server side logs, network traffic capture and the dummy adapter you created

Comment: The server error is the same as that of the JavaAdapter.
The dummy code and the request were added to the question.